# Getting Lavalamp jQuery plugin to work with dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, drop-down-menu, lavalamp

I have a problem with the [jQuery Lavalamp plugin](http://gmarwaha.com/blog/?p=7). It works perfectly with a single-level menu, but after adding a dropdown it gets a bit lost. Here's what I mean: http://screenr.com/0fS.

Of course what I would like to achieve is for the lavalamp background to stay on the Portfolio item when the user hovers over the subitems.

I guess it's a matter of changing the plugin slightly, so here's the full code of the plugin. What's needed is just a simple way to make the lavalamp stop at the current stage when `<li>`'s children are hovered and then go back to working normally after. Here's the full plugin code for reference!

```
(function($) {
$.fn.lavaLamp = function(o) {
o = $.extend({ fx: "linear", speed: 500, click: function(){} }, o || {});

return this.each(function() {
    var me = $(this), noop = function(){},
        $back = $('<li class="back"><div class="left"></div></li>').appendTo(me),
        $li = $("li", this), curr = $("li.current", this)[0] || $($li[0]).addClass("current")[0];

    $li.not(".back").hover(function() {
        move(this);
    }, noop);

    $(this).hover(noop, function() {
        move(curr);
    });

    $li.click(function(e) {
        setCurr(this);
        return o.click.apply(this, [e, this]);
    });

    setCurr(curr);

    function setCurr(el) {
        $back.css({ "left": el.offsetLeft+"px", "width": el.offsetWidth+"px" });
        curr = el;
    };

    function move(el) {
        $back.each(function() {
            $(this).dequeue(); }
        ).animate({
            width: el.offsetWidth,
            left: el.offsetLeft
        }, o.speed, o.fx);
    };

});
};
})(jQuery);`
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the fix for this is to change the hover() in the lavalamp to mouseover as show on the following page..

http://hekimian-williams.com/?p=146

Answer (score 0):

I added additional class to top level li and updated the js:

```
$li = $("li.top-level-item", this),
```