# jquery lavalamp children don't stay

Tags: jquery, lavalamp

Good morning.

I got a problem with lavalamp, I have a web app structure like

Home
Category1
--Product1
--Product2
--Product3
Category2
--Product4
--Product5
--Product6

I have a top navigation with Home, Category1 and Category2.
But when I go in Productx, the lavalamp stick my bar on home.

For now i only have

```
 $('#topNavigation').lavaLamp({
     fx: 'easeOutQuint',
     speed: 500
 });
```

And my menu

```
 <ul class="topNavigation">
    <li class="backLava" >
       <div class="leftLava"></div>
    </li>
    <li>home</li>
    <li>Category1</li>
    <li>Category2</li>
 </ul>
```

CSS

```
#topNavigation .backLava {
   background: none;
   border-bottom: 8px solid #1f6737;
   z-index: 0;
   top: 3px !important;
}
```

So when i click on Category1 and click on link to Product1 I want lavalamp to stay on Category1, but for now he return to home.

Anyone have a solution ?

i know it's possible by changing

```
$li.not(".back").hover(function(){move(this)},noop);
```

by

$li.not(".back").mouseover(function(){move(this)},noop);

[Getting Lavalamp jQuery plugin to work with dropdown menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005939/getting-lavalamp-jquery-plugin-to-work-with-dropdown-menu)

but i don't find it... in v 1.4.min

---

EDIT:

Found the solution : in my navigation constructor look at the current page and if its a child add the selectedLava class manually

Comment: Found the solution : in my navigation constructor look at the current page and if its a child add the selectedLava class manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution : in my navigation constructor look at the current page and if its a child add the selectedLava class manually

Comment: Nope. Answers should be answers and not edits to the question. Please correct that.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).